# Pythonic way of looping over variable that is either an element or a list

Tags: python

I am trying to use a for loop with a variable that is either an element(of a list) or a list. The code I have now, I find very ugly.

```
for x in test if isinstance(test, list) else [test]:
    print(x)
```

Any pythonic way of improving on this?

Comment: what is `test`? Is it an instance of some custom class?

Comment: why not just print your variable if it is an element and only use the for loop when it's necessary? It's silly to create one element list and use a for loop to print that element.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Instance: test is either `[{'test': 'test'}, {'test': 'test'}, {'test': 'test'}]` or `{'test': 'test'}`

Comment: This is all part of something quite a lot bigger, but the point is that in the actual code the `test` variable is part of a dict, in which `test` is the value to a key. This makes for very long lines of code, which is ugly/unreadable. For example: `rep_list = adaptation['Representation'] if isinstance(adaptation['Representation'], list) else [adaptation['Representation']]`

Comment: I think what you've got is OK.  I note that you really need to test if `test` is a `list` because your singleton elements might be `str` (for example) and therefore iterable.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't completely clear - by "OK" I meant, "as Pythonic as is reasonably achievable for this requirement".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might want to include different types (rather than `list`) in your check, and a quick way of doing that would be:

```
def is_iterable(x):
    return type(x) in [list, tuple] # or just isinstance(x, list)
```

---

With that, I would probably end up doing something like:

```
if is_iterable(test):
    for x in test:
        do_stuff(x)
else:
    do_stuff(test)
```

Or if you expect any return:

```
if is_iterable(test):
    return [do_stuff(x) for x in test]
else:
    return [do_stuff(test)]
```

I don't know whether is the more pythonic way (or not) of doing that, but for me, is the most readable one. If you really really want to reduce space, probably your option is the way to go, as is the best practical way of getting a one-liner. However, I don't think there is any performance improvement (maybe just quite the opposite).

Another last option, if your `do_stuff` is not defined as a function, and thus you don't want to copy-paste code (never do that), would be to just get the assignment out:

```
test = test if is_iterable(test) else [test]
for x in test:
    do_stuff
    ...
```

But this is in essence the same as what you already have. In my personal experience, it is usually useful to get all the *preprocessing* out of the *calculation* step and make sure all the parameters have valid types. Then just perform whatever operation you need to do on them.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because of it's completeness, and have already gone with a solution similar to your last example.

Comment: @Snuggert yep the last example is just the same as your proposed method (with the check out of the foor loop). In this case you only want to iterate over one list. However, in practice, if you have a function that accepts multiple parameters of different types, it is much more clear to *parse* them all before hand and put them into a *valid* format, and then perform all the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

[isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and x or [x] for x in test]
```

This gives a list where each element is unchanged if it is already a list and is made in to a list if not already.

Comment: I don't really see how this is more pythonic than: `[x in test if isinstance(test, list) else [test]]` Not to negate your input or anything.

Comment: It's a list comprehension which is a more pythonic idiom. It also makes the execution much quicker on a larger list.

Comment: The other major factor at play here is Python's "better to ask for forgiveness rather than ask permission" principle, discussed here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing

Comment: But this makes the code longer again obviously if you add a try-except. I think the code you have is already pythonic and I agree my suggestion is only a little more pythonic. There's no other way to make it more pythonic though as you can't have else statements in a list comprehension - only if statements

Comment: Slightly OT but I don't think this is quite the right test.  In the example, `x` can be a `str` which is Iterable but should still be put into a list.